# How to automate selection of column for VBA (macro)

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently writing my first vba code (macro - excel) for work.
I have been checking online and could not quite find an answer that solves my problem.

I have written the below code so far:

```
Sub UpdateRdata()
'
' UpdateRdata Macro
' change formula to use new data from CSV file
'

   ** Range("R3").Formula = "=C3-E27"**
    Range("R3").AutoFill Range("R3:R9")

    If Range("R3") > 0 Then
       Range("S3").Value = "NOK"
    End If
    If Range("R3") = 0 Then
       Range("S3").Value = "OK"
    End If
    Range("S3").AutoFill Range("S3:S9")
 

End Sub
```

Now the issue is that everytime I add a new data in the column to the right Id like the macro to recognize and adapt the formuula. (i have hilighted it in bold, so the E27 is static but C3 should change to E3, F3, G3, etc. everytime i create a new reporting for each month).

Hope it makes sense. Is it possible to combine it with autofill? I have only referenced one cell but added autofill in order for the output/value of the formula to drag down in column R, R3 to R9

If possible please let me know which is the best approach. I tried with offset and activecell but always receive error messages

Comment: If you want "E27" to be static, you need to replace it by "$E$27".

Comment: Also **1.** no need to autofill. You can directly enter the formula in the entire range in one go. `Range("R3:R9").Formula = "=C3-$E$27"` **2.** Remove the 1st `End If` and change the 2nd `If` to `ElseIf` so that it become one IF THEN ELSEIF statement. **3.** `Range("S3").AutoFill Range("S3:S9")` Again this can be written as `Range("S3:S9").Formula = Range("S3").Formula`

Comment: The way you have it, you'd also check for the third row and then set every row to that value instead of checking per row. 
Also, with new columns, do you mean to manually fill in data then in E3:E9, F3:F9, etc. and expect the calculations from vba to expand towards T3:T9, U3:U9, etc.?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Notus_Panda - not quite, i want the reference of the formula lt adjust automatically (take data from columns E3:E9, then next period from F3:F9, and so on)

Comment: If there's already data from C to Q (or however far the data reaches), you could work with `FormulaR1C1` instead unless you don't want formulas to remain, then you'll have to calculate with `.Column` and `If (colNumb And 1) = 0 Then` for uneven columns (like your R column) and probably trigger the calculation in a WorkSheet_Change event, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change